# Are there changes that need to be made for STS authentication going from one VM to multiple VMs in an availability set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, azure, single-sign-on

I currently have a VM in Azure that's hosting a MVC website, that has authentication via a secure token service. For better SLA / redundancy, I'm looking to move it to two VMS. Are there any changes that will need to be made or planned for, or will it work exactly the same without any modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've written you should see no change in behaviour.  The STS issues a token which the RP (your MVC app) looks for and may do additional processing on.  If you have any session state tied to a user session you will need to ensure that it is shared between the two hosts running your MVC app (this is standard practice for any ASP.Net web app hosted on multiple servers).

Comment: Thanks! As a thought exercise, does this apply to standard FBA too? (as in, are FBA authentication cookies instance-agnostic, or will it need to be shared between hosts like sessions?)

Comment: As long as your machine key is the same on both instances (again standard practice in a web farm) you should be fine if you ensure session state is properly managed between instances.